# How to filter a predicate based on nsarray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nspredicate

I have the following uisearchbar delegate method.  I want this method to search my objects arrayofterms property to see if any of the elements match the searchText parameter.

Will this work? :

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {


    [self.filteredArray removeAllObjects];
    // something like this is what the objects array attribute will look like: NSArray *arrayofterms = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Miguel", @"Ben", @"Adam", @"Melissa", nil];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.arrayofterms contains[c] %@",searchText];
    self.filteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.planDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

    }
```

Comment: *Does* it work? You tell us.

Comment: No it doesn't because it is comparing a text string against an array.  I want it to compare against the contents of the array.

Comment: With your predicate, the following functionality is implemented:  check if the `arrayofterms` property of each element of the `self.planaDataArray` contains `searchText`. Unfortunately I didn't get what you'd like to achieve, could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Does the array contain strings?  Then ...

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *string, NSDictionary *bind) {
    return [string isEqualToString:searchText];
}];

self.filteredArray = [[self.planDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

If the planDataArray contains some other sort of object, maybe a custom object, then ...

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(MyCustomObject *object, NSDictionary *bind) {
    NSString *string = object.someStringProperty;
    return [string isEqualToString:searchText];
}];
```